# Rails undefined method none for ActiveModel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I run into an undefined method error running testing the following code in a Pundit Policy.
I'm teaching myself RoR so this could be just very obvious. However I have no idea why this error is occurring. The scope seems to be the Project class I want to test and seem to be an ActiveRecord class. Looking at the API documentation is should contain the method none but according to the test run is does not.

```
class ProjectPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
    class Scope < Scope
        def initialize(user, scope)
            @user = user;
            @scope = scope;
        end 

        def resolve
            return scope.none if user.nil?
            return scope.all if user.admin?

            scope.joins(:roles).where(roles: {user_id: user})
        end
    end
end
```

This is the rspec test I run.

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe ProjectPolicy do

    let(:user) { User.new }

    subject { described_class }

    context "policy_scope" do
        subject { Pundit.policy_scope(user, Project) }

        let!(:project) { FactoryGirl.create :project }
        let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create :user }

        it "is empty for anonymous users" do
            expect(Pundit.policy_scope(nil, project)).to be_empty
        end
    end
end
```

This is the stack trace when running the test.

```
1) ProjectPolicy policy_scope is empty for anonymous users
   Failure/Error: return scope.none if user.nil?

   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `none' for #<Project:0x007fb0f45c0010>
   # /Users/mquellhorst/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.4/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
   # ./app/policies/project_policy.rb:6:in `resolve'
   # /Users/mquellhorst/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pundit-1.0.1/lib/pundit.rb:49:in `policy_scope'
   # ./spec/policies/project_policy_spec.rb:51:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
   # /Users/mquellhorst/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:236:in `instance_exec'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `Pundit.policy_scope(nil, project)` with an *instance* of `Project` (the one you created in `let(:project)`). `ActiveRecord#none` is defined on the *class* `Project`, which is why it works in the `subject` block. Compare:

```
Project.none     #=> #<ActiveRecord:Relation []>
Project.new.none #=> Your current error
```

Comment: Thanks!! I see what you mean. It's working now, I gave policy_scope the class Project instead of an instance: Pundit.policy_scope(nil, Project) :)